# Estimate for Expectation of Reciprocal Bessel Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $W=(W_{t})_{t\geq 0}$ be a standard $3$-dimensional Brownian motion, and let $a\neq 0\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Consider the $3$-dimensional inverse Bessel process defined by $Y_{t}:=\frac{1}{|a+W_{t}|}$. My goal is to show that $\mathbb{E}[Y_{t}]\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$. The source which stated this limit as true described the proof as quite computational. I don't see why this is the case if one doesn't care about the exact value of $\mathbb{E}[Y_{t}]$. Indeed, by dilation and translation invariance, and the homogeneity of $|x|^{-1}$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y_{t}]\lesssim t^{-3/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}|x+a|^{-1}e^{-\frac{|x|^{2}}{2t}}dx=t^{-3/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}|x|^{-1}e^{-\frac{|x-a|^{2}}{2t}}dx&=t^{-1/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}|x|^{-1}e^{-\frac{|x-t^{-1/2}a|^{2}}{2}}dx\\
\end{align*}
Splitting the RHS into the regions $|x|\leq 1$ and $|x|>1$, we obtain the estimate
\begin{align*}
\leq t^{-1/2}\int_{|x|\leq 1}|x|^{-1}dx+t^{-1/2}\int_{|x|\geq 1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x-t^{-1/2}a|^{2}}dx\lesssim t^{-1/2}+t^{-1/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x|^{2}}dx
\end{align*}
where the RHS follows from the local integrability of $|x|^{-1}$ and another application of translation invariance. Evidently, this expression $\rightarrow 0$, $t\rightarrow\infty$. (N.B. The Vinogradov notation $A\lesssim B$ means $A\leq CB$ for some constant $C$ independent of $A$ and $B$).

Am I making an error in my calculations, or is this just not difficult?

Comment: I don't see why this should be difficult. You reasoning seems correct.

Comment: @zhoraster: Thanks. I think the author must have meant that calculating the integral in terms of some known function (such as erf) is done [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567816/calculate-the-expectation-of-inverse-bessel-process?rq=1) is more involved.